How to Make UserControl Autodock Dockstyle Top in vb.net
I'm Trying to Make UserControl Autodock Dockstyle Top when when I drag from toolbox in form in vb.net
Please Guide me
Thanks
Code in usercontrol
Public Class usercontroldocktop
    Private Sub usercontroldocktop_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim frm As Form = MyBase.FindForm()
        frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
    End Sub
End Class



If you want a control to behave a certain way then you need to write that behaviour into the control's code. I would hope that you don't need it explained to you how to set a property in code.

@jmcilhinney , Thanks for your response, Please Guide me

Set the property in the code for the control. If you don't know how to set a property, consult a beginner tutorial.
